# How to create an application that has some functionality and share it so someone else can put it on their website?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, project, cdn

If I create a small web application on my desktop (html and js files) and want to share the functionality of it so my friend could use it on his website, how can I do that?

For example, if I want to use the benefits of bootstrap to quickly make changes, they instruct me to download this file

`<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper --> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

1. What is this file? I'm assuming all the js code and logic to their
   platform lives in this file, yes?
2. If I want to build my own
   application and share it so others can use it, how would I do it?

**Sample application:** a user copies the CDN file link, they add it to their index.html file at the top of the page, when they reload their website a modal pops up in 5 seconds. That's it.

Comment: Yes, you can upload your code to some CDN or to Github and share it, then other people can use your functions or variables as long as they are in the global scope.

Comment: @JoshuaRodriguez if I upload it to a CDN, do I upload just the javascript file? Not the index.html or CSS files, right? Also, any specific CDN provider you recommend?

Comment: You only need to upload the code, other people will only use your javascript functions and variables right? If they need to user your css or something like that, you can upload it, but isn't needed because you want to share your functions and not your styles.

You don't need a CDN unless you're going to use thousands of gb of bandwidth, you can do that only uploading the file to you website or something related and just share the link of the file.

Comment: @JoshuaRodriguez I tried saving my main.js file in Google Drive and WordPress. Didn't work?